# Can honey bee colony simulation be done in Blender?

Tags: animation, particles

I am fairly new to blender and I want to simulate an environment of bees flying in and out of a bee hive, collecting nectar from flowers which are randomly placed in the environment and go back to the hive. In the hive, a few bees should be simply flying around.

Can this be done in blender? Should I use additional modules?

Comment: Blender can do almost *Anything.* Its limitations only lie within your skill and imagination, Blender's full potential can only be unlocked when you escape the realm of reason, and go nuts.

Answer (score 5):

I expect you can do a good job of that in blender, within the particle physics settings you can find some [boids options](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:FR/2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Boids), these can be used to simulate a flock of birds so it should do bees just as well. I would have some empties moving from place to place that a swarm would follow to specify the timing of the bees moving.

You can use multiple particle systems so you may want one for the bees hanging around the hive; one (or more) for each group(s) that goes off to the flowers; and one (or more) for each group(s) that returns to the hive.

You can also use particles to place the flowers around the scene.